# Is regex from Java buggy or am i missing something?

Tags: java, regex

With this regex :

```
private static String p = "^\\(([-+]?([1-8]?\\d(\\.\\d+)?|90(\\.0+)?))\\,([-+]?(180(\\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\\d)|([1-9]?\\d))(\\.\\d+)?))\\)$";//"^(\\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\\-?\d+(\\.\d+)?)$";
```

It is impossible for me to get the values and i don't understand why...

With an input like that :

```
(50,180)    //or even
(-50,-180)
```

Why my regex doesn't get me the number 180 and can get the value 50??
I mean, my Pattern object can get always the first value after parenthesis and before "," but can't get the value after ",".

What's the problem with my regex ?

My code:

```
private static String patternGeographicCoordinates = "^\\(([-+]?([1-8]?\\d(\\.\\d+)?|90(\\.0+)?))\\,([-+]?(180(\\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\\d)|([1-9]?\\d))(\\.\\d+)?))\\)$";
....
Pattern geographicCoordinates = Pattern.compile(patternGeographicCoordinates);
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
....
Matcher m1 = geographicCoordinates.matcher(line); //line is a line from a file (String)
....
if(m1.matches()){
    System.out.println("IT DID WORK, LINE: "+line+", M.GROUP: "+m1.group(3));
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

Comment: You can be fairly certain that you're missing something.

Comment: what is missing in your question is the "line" variable - what input do you feed into the matcher?

Comment: Is your input format just like : (50,180) or there's more to it? If it is just that consider looking at your regex again. May be it is too much.

Comment: Going to edit my code then for "line" questions

Comment: my advice is also, NOT to use this regex for this task. read in the file, assuming it contains valid numbers, you could use much simpler regex (or no regex at all) to detect formatting problems, then once you've created a bunch of objects, validate the object using a geo coordinate validator, that checks the number ranges for correctness. then you can reject invalid points, or do whatever you need. Don't try to use regex for everything.

Comment: It is advisable to test your regexp with online tools like this http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html or this http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com
This way you would know if it's your regexp or it's your java code. Hence, you would not need to ask this question.

Comment: @nolexa Ok, didn't know about that... But my regex seems like working well ! I don't understand why it is doing some checks, for example,
"
3: [-1,-1] null
4: [-1,-1] null
"
with an input : (15,14)
What's the point with that then ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just remove the parenthesis and split around the comma?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
...
theString = StringUtils.strip(theString,"()"));
String[] tokens = theString.split(",");
Double number2 = Double.parse(tokens[1]);
```

Comment: I think this is a nice way in viewing differently. Thank you for that ! :)

Comment: BTW with this you need to rely on third party jar from commons.

Comment: Why include another library to do something that can be accomplished as easily in Java?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use regex anyway, you can do it like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([-]?\\d+)\\s*\\,\\s*([-]?\\d+)\\)$");
String input = "(-50,-80)";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.find())
{
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
   System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

See demo [here](http://ideone.com/X13BKT)

Comment: If I could i would also validate your answer ! But I can't unfortunately :( Because both of your answers are valid and ty for that ! I upvoted your answer by the way

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at wrong group indices. Check your regexp with this parser: https://regex101.com/

Here are the matching groups for the input `(50,180)`:

```
1.  [1-3]   `50`
2.  [1-3]   `50`
5.  [4-7]   `180`
6.  [4-7]   `180`
```

**Update**

The regexp is made for more complex inputs than you supply in your example, that's why there are groups with `null` values. The additional groups are for decimal parts and special cases (apparently meaningful for coordinate parsing).

Look at the input `(90.00,180.00)`. It's parsed into the following groups:

```
1.  [1-6]   `90.00`
2.  [1-6]   `90.00`
4.  [3-6]   `.00`
5.  [7-13]  `180.00`
6.  [7-13]  `180.00`
7.  [10-13] `.00`
```

Now group 4 is matching `(\.0+)?` and group 7 is matching `(\.\d+)`. You see that `|90`is an alternative, a special case of 90.00 degrees presumably. That's why group 3 is still empty but 4 is filled.

With input `(85.21,150.34)` you will get more groups filled:

```
1.  [1-6]   `85.21`
2.  [1-6]   `85.21`
3.  [3-6]   `.21`
5.  [7-13]  `150.34`
6.  [7-13]  `150.34`
8.  [7-10]  `150`
9.  [7-10]  `150`
11. [10-13] `.34`
```

Now group 3 is filled, but not the group 4, because it's `[1-8]?\d` case.

Also, since you have nested groups, same values are assigned twice: to 1 and 2 for instance.

Comment: yeah i saw that :/ But I don't understand why he is having "null" for number 3,4,...